# Do quick-release drugs increase physiological dependence?

Tags: addiction, drug-tolerance, drug-withdrawal

I'm aware that quick-release drugs are more addictive in that they have a stronger psychological habit-forming effect, but assuming that the dose is kept constant, what effect does using a quicker-releasing pill have on physiological dependence and tolerance?

I would have assumed that there would be less tolerance at the same dose as you're essentially taking a bunch of miniature tolerance breaks every day as opposed to having more constant amounts of the drug in your system.

Comment: Can you please provide a source for the statement that quick-release drugs are more addictive? And what exactly is quick release? Do you mean rapid acting/onset? What class of drugs are you referring to? Many rapid-onset drugs are not addictive at all.

Comment: [Citation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165614704003219). Is there any controversy over that point?  Yes: Rapid acting vs regular or regular vs extended release.  I am interested in all classes of tolerance-forming drugs.  I would assume less tolerance would form with all of them, but if this is not the case, I would be interested to know why.

Comment: Iv ceftriaxone is a very rapid onset drug that to my knowledge has never caused dependency issues. I could blame at least a thousand more. Your question is I’ll-phrased or ill thought out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the confusion is. I just said I'm interested in tolerance-forming drugs. If ceftriaxone doesn't cause tolerance, I'm not interested in it. If it does cause tolerance, I would like to know if releasing the drug faster would causes more or less tolerance.

Comment: If someone is not aware of the general pattern (e.g. tolerance tends to decrease for quick-release depressants, but increase for stimulants), but does know information about a specific class (e.g. extended-release benzodiazepines form more tolerance than regular release ones at the same dose) that would be very welcome.